# Machine Learning Book. Where is X?

Tags: c#, variables

I just purchased this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430267674) and I am at the very beginning and having problems.

```
public class DataReader
{
    private static Observation ObservationFactory(string data)
    {
        var commaSeparated = data.Split(',');
        var label = commaSeparated[0];
    // ERROR HERE
        var pixels = commaSeparated.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

        return new Observation(label, pixels);
    }

    public static Observation[] ReadObservations(string dataPath)
    {  
         var data = File.ReadAllLines(dataPath)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(ObservationFactory)
        .ToArray();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Maybe I am missing something but where does the `x` come from? I am super disappointed because I can't find any mention of the `x` variable anywhere.

Comment: I totally cant get this thing to read my code..............

Comment: At least AwokeKnowing understand this stupid confusing format.

Comment: The term you should google is `Lambda Expressions C#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x is a parameter.  so there where you see it is where it's being declared.  You are creating a lambda function

```
x => Convert.ToInt32(x)
```

and passing that as the parameter to .Select

if you've done any javascript this would be like.

```
$('div').click(function(x){alert(x.target.id)});
```

Comment: and how does this answer my question?

Comment: nevermind figured it out. it had nothing to do with the lamba expression. it was a typo